# Why do we need operator functions in python?

Tags: python, operators

Why would one use [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)s in python when we have almost all of them available inline such as [/,*,-,+,<,>,...]?

When would we need to use these operator functions as opposed to the inline operators?

Comment: So you can have custom comparators for custom object. Or so you could swap out an operator for another one easily. Lots of reasons. So many that this question definitely is too broad for StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: it's a convenience library. Operators are part of *source code*, this provides *functions* that work equivalently to an operator. So `operator.add` is the same as `def add(x, y): return x + y` or `lambda x,y: x + y`. This is such a common use-case that they created a library.

Comment: "operator functions as opposed to the inline operators?" **whenever you need a function**, of course. Since operators aren't *objects*, they are features of the *source code*, they are part of the syntax. So, you can do something like `map(operator.add, some_iterable)`, you cannot do `map(+, some_iterable)`, that would by a syntax error (in some languages, usually in functional programming langauges, operators are merely functions, not in Python, though)

Comment: `operator.add` is typically more efficient than `lambda x, y: x + y`, too; user-defined functions are relatively expensive to call, and the `operator` modules tries to import an extension module `_operator` to implement these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of why you might like to be able to call an operator as a function, consider the following code:

```
    if op == "+":
        return num1 + num2
    elif op == "-":
        return num1 - num2
    elif op == "*":
        return num1 * num2
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"invalid operator {op}")
```

With `operator` this can be written more easily as:

```
    return {
        "+": operator.add,
        "-": operator.sub,
        "*": operator.mul,
    }[op](num1, num2)
```